# CFileDialog constructor can't spot TRUE and fopen(str,"r") error

Tags: fopen, cfiledialog

I call the `CFileDialog` constructor in the following method:

```
CFileDialog FileDlg(TRUE, ".txt", NULL, 0, strFilter);
```

according to the parameters in the `CFileDialog` constructor, the first parameter should be `BOOL`, but my compiler thinks it's `int` instead of `BOOL`. Can you tell me why?

Besides, in the code, when I use `fopen(str,"r")`, the error is no conversion function from `CSring to const char*`. Appreciate your discussion.

The code is:

```
void OnFileOpen()
{
    CClientDC dc(this);
    CString str;
    CRect rc;
    FILE *ifp;
    char strFilter[] = { "TXT Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files(*.*)|*.*||" };
    CFileDialog FileDlg(TRUE, ".txt", NULL, 0, strFilter);
    if (FileDlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
        str = FileDlg.GetFileName();
        ifp = fopen(str,"r");
        dc.TextOutW(350, 50, "File Opened: " + str);
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            fscanf(ifp, "%d %d", &pt[i].x, &pt[i].y);
            rc = CRect(pt[i].x - 30, pt[i].y - 30, pt[i].x + 30, pt[i].y + 30);
            dc.Ellipse(rc);
            rc = CRect(pt[i].x - 1, pt[i].y - 1, pt[i].x + 1, pt[i].y + 1);
            dc.Rectangle(rc);
        }
        fclose(ifp);
    }
}
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: `BOOL` *is* `int`. It was used as a replacement for `bool` before the latter became part of the C++ standard. Most, if not all, WINAPI functions and structures that deal with booleans use `BOOL` and not `bool`.